# C# (sharp) reading random line from txt file

Tags: c#, random, line, text-files

Can anyone tell me how to read random line from txt file? I want to read random line from txt file and show only that line in textBox.
Code examples would be great!
Thanx in foward

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745934/read-random-line-from-a-file-c/3745973#3745973  Will work with files of any size and doesn't require you to read the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 9):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
var r = new Random();
var randomLineNumber = r.Next(0, lines.Length - 1);
var line = lines[randomLineNumber];
```

Comment: Don't allocate a `new Random()` every call, the result will not be random if the calls occur too close together in time.  A thread-static `Random` should be used instead.  See [Random number generator only generating one random number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/767999).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to read all the lines to memory and pick one randomly. Assuming that all the lines can fit in memory.

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
Random rnd1 = new Random();
Console.WriteLine(allLines[rnd1.Next(allLines.Length)]);
```

Comment: Arrays have no Count property...

Comment: This does not work... you're missing the part where you actually get the line from the line array. Also, what Mark said.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code sample:

```
        int lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\file.txt").Length;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randomLineNum = rnd.Next(lineCount);
        int indicator = 0;

        using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\file.txt"))
        {
            while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
            {
                if(indicator==randomLineNum)
                {
                    //do your stuff here
                    break;
                }
                indicator++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Now why would you go to the trouble of reading all the lines into memory just to get the count, and then *re-read* the file to get the line you want? You can just `ReadAllLines` and then select from the array.