# Get line number when reading a file

Tags: c#

I am reading all lines in a text file using C# 7 as follows:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(file)) {    
  String line;    
  while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {

  }          
}
```

For each line I also need to get the line number.

StreamReader does not seem to have a method for getting the line number.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Am I not understanding something? Why can't you just count them yourself?

Answer (score 4):

I'd just create an integer to keep track of the line number myself.

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(file)) {    
    var lineNumber = 0;
    String line;    
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
        ...

        lineNumber++;
    }          
}
```

Microsoft also uses such a variable to count the lines in one of the examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time

Comment: I believe the question is more about the line number being referred to here being the actual index of the line returned from the file and not a matter of incrementing the count of the lines being returned.

Answer (score 2):

You should use your own local variable for it, like that:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(file)) {    
      String line;    
      int lineNum=0;
      while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
         ++lineNum;
      }          
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other solutions here, I like to use [File.ReadAllLines(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a `string[]` result and then `for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)...`.

Answer (score 0):

you can compute line number by your self:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(file)) {    
  String line;
  int n = 0;
  while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
    n++;
  }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already solved and [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239603/how-to-get-the-line-number-of-specific-text-in-string-in-c-sharp/69638997#69638997) but I want to share an [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437716/search-text-file-using-c-sharp-and-display-the-line-number-and-the-complete-line). The code just returns the line number where it founds a part of the string given, to have the exact one just replace "Contains" with "Equals".

```
public int GetLineNumber(string lineToFind) {        
    int lineNum = 0;
    string line;
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
        lineNum++;
        if (line.Contains(lineToFind)) {
            return lineNum;
        }
    }
    file.Close();
    return -1;
}
```