# How to randomize the text in a label

Tags: c#, random, label, text-files

How to read a random line from a text file and change the text in the label to be that random line, then after a drag and drop which i have coded(below) the label will change the text. The language is c#. I am a beginner so i apologize if this is a stupid question.

```
private void txt_carbs_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            e.Effect = e.AllowedEffect;
        // check if the held data format is text
        // if it is text allow the effect 
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        // if it is not text do nothing
    }

    private void txt_protien_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            e.Effect = e.AllowedEffect;
        // check if the held data format is text
        // if it is text allow the effect 
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        // if it is not text do nothing
    }

    private void txt_fats_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            e.Effect = e.AllowedEffect;
            // check if the held data format is text
            // if it is text allow the effect 
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        // if it is not text do nothing
    }

    private void txt_fats_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        txt_fats.Text += e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
        //add the text into the text box
    }

    private void txt_protien_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        txt_protien.Text += e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
        //add the text into the text box
    }

    private void txt_carbs_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        txt_carbs.Text += e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
        //add the text into the text box
    }

    private void lbl_term_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_term.DoDragDrop(lbl_term.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        // get the text from the label
    }
```

Also this is how ive been changing the labels text however this isn't it isn't randomized

```
StreamReader score =
            new StreamReader(file_location);
        label10.Text = score.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most efficient implementation in the world, but you could do the following to get a random line from a file, if the file isn't too big, as described in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745951/2609288):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file_location);
Random rand = new Random();
return lines[rand.Next(lines.Length)];
```

Comment: As a prewarning to the OP declaring a new random every time wouldn't make it as random as they may hope... [Example](https://ideone.com/3QTGxE).. Easy enough to find the solution to this problem though ;)

Comment: @Sayse: Agree, it's not perfect. But for the OP's purposes in the example above, it should be OK. Better would be to initialize the `Random` object as a class static, and re-use the same object each time.